# Traveling to Tenerife with bikes vs car rental

Tags: car-rentals, bicycles, luggage-storage, tenerife

Hello fellow travelers!

In a couple days we're travelling to Tenerife for 2 weeks (me and my wife). We'll be carrying two bike suitcases plus a single, big regular suitcase.

We'd like to rent a car and spread our time on Tenerife across a couple places located in different parts of the island (we'll probably spend around 4-5 days in one place).

The problem is how to travel with bikes (and bike suitcases) in a rental car.

I see two options:

1. Rent a car with big cargo capacity like vw caddy. Put everything inside. The downside is we'll likely have to pack the bikes into the suitcases each time we'll be moving from one place to another.
2. Find a storage where we could stash the bike suitcases for two weeks. Unpack the bike upon arrival, rent a regular car with a bike rack.

Option 2 seems to be smartest but there are some caveats:

1. Renting a car with a bike rack - after a quick research I see that only cicar has such options but they're a bit pricey - I'd pay 100eur more for Opel Corsa with rack than I would for VW caddy somewhere else.
2. Storage for bike suitcases - we couldn't find any place near the airport, the closest one seems to be around Santa Cruz.

Let me know about your experiences and tips!

Comment: I don't understand why you would want a car if you intend to travel with bike?

Comment: Renting a van or similar vehicle is almost certainly the easiest solution, though may be more costly. Finding a car with cycle rack will be harder than finding a bigger vehicle. Exactly how big are the bike suitcases though - you can get soft bags which you need to dismantle the bike to fit in, or much bigger cases. A large car may well be enough, depending on the size. You need to work out exactly what size of vehicle will do.

Comment: Those asking why the OP needs a bike and a car should note that the island is about 80 x 50 km (50 x 30 miles) at the widest part. It's possible to cycle, but it depends on your fitness and keenness.

Comment: @StuartF if they've got hard bike cases to protect fragile bikes on the plane, they're not likely to want to swap to soft bags.  Even a wheels-off hard case is pretty big; the only reason a bag isn't is that it can be folded.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Mt Teide is the highest mountain in all of Spain. Wanting to cycle doesn't oblige one to make the ascent by bike.

Comment: Aside: when I visited, the airport hire car concession I had booked with was running a scam. "The car has a full tank of fuel, we are charging you for this, bring the car back with an empty tank." For an island size 80 x 50 km it's quite hard to use a tank of fuel in a week, but my plan was to make day trips to cover the whole island, so I wasn't far off.